# How to change a font color in a DataTemplate from codebehind?

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate

I have a XAML DataTemplate like this being applied to ListBoxItems. Notice the grid near the bottom. What I would like to do is change the color of the bound text based on the value of the text, as in 'Status: ERROR' where 'ERROR' is red.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA9A9A9" Offset="1.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F4F5" Offset="0.0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.RowSpan="3">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F1" Offset="1.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F4F5" Offset="0.0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Status:"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Status}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label Content="{Binding Bookmark}" ContentStringFormat="Last Bookmark: {0}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

How do I change the color of the text text in that bound Status `<Label>` from code behind (C#)?

(Or, if not from code behind, how in XAML? Status can have 3 text values (Queued, Running, and Error) and each is matched with an assigned color (Blue, Green, and Red))

Comment: Use a `<DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @SLaks hint, I was able to work out the complete answer. Here it is for others:

This:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Status:"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Status}" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Becomes this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Status:"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Status}" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="RUNNING">
                        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="ERROR">
                        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="QUEUED">
                        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```